# Javaxfx: MVP (Supervising Controller) must view keep reference to presenter (controller)

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx

I want to implement MVP (Supervising Controller) with JavaFX. I've studied several examples in internet and saw that view keep reference to presenter. Is this right?

I thought that view should not know about presenter at all. There is biderectional data binding between view and model VIEW<->MODEL although view doesn't keep reference to model. And presenter (controller) which knows about view (but works with view via interface) and model and handles all events. Model knows neither view nor presenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually explain the difference as follows:

- If your view has a reference to a model and/or a controller/presenter, that indicates your view has at least some responsibility to set itself up or maintain itself. In this case your controller isn't fully responsible for the view, so you call it a Supervising Controller.
- If your view has no references to a model or controller/presenter whatsoever, it cannot do anything on its own and is completely passive, so you're using the Passive View pattern.

If you're using FXML, you're most likely using Passive View, as FXML cannot specify any logic (other than maybe a name of a controller class and names of event handler methods) and your controller is responsible for setting up the view and maintaining it.